# SXA datasource token is not working for Sitecore JSS rendering component

Tags: sxa, jss

we are adding a JSS rendering component in SXA site. We have added the below query in JSS component data source location.

`query:$site/*[@@name='Data']/*[@@templatename='Content Blocks Folder']`

It is working if we add direct path in datasource location.

we want to refer the data from the Data folder of the Site.

---

```
Error Rendering Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JsLayoutRenderer: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.Http.HttpNodeInstance.InvokeExport[T](NodeInvocationInfo invocationInfo)
at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.InvokeExport[T](String moduleName, String exportNameOrNull, Object[] args)
at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.DefaultNodeServices.InvokeExportWithPossibleRetry[T](String moduleName, String exportedFunctionName, Object[] args, Boolean allowRetry)
at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.DefaultNodeServices.InvokeExport[T](String moduleName, String exportedFunctionName, Object[] args)
at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.NodeRenderEngine.Invoke[T](String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)
at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.PerformRender(TextWriter writer, IRenderEngine renderEngine, String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)
at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
```

Comment: I am not familiar with code but I think that **SXA** specific queries might not be resolved before value from the field is used by **JSS**. You can either do it by yourself if you will find a good place (use `ITokenResolver` service or run through `resolveTokens` pipeline), wait till someone will help you with that (if any1 had the same case and solved it) or report it to support. and ask for a hotfix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, JSS can coexist with SXA on the same Sitecore instance, as a separate site. JSS is not currently capable of acting as an SXA tenant or using SXA's experience editor extensions (i.e. drag and drop components, variants, partials, etc), or any of SXA's features.

https://jss.sitecore.com/help#can-i-use-jss-with-sxa

Comment: will it won't work for SXA tokens as well?